# Multithreading in Mac OS X

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, macos

What's the equivalent of Window's CreateProcess() and WaitForSingleObject() in Mac OS X?

Wanted my C-Program to pause while my .app has finished running.

Comment: `fork()`, `exec()`, `wait()`/`waitpid()`, and pthreads?

Comment: or maybe you could `sleep()`?

Answer (score 1):

The closest to CreateProcess() in OS X would be doing a fork() and exec(). But if you are trying to launch a .app from a C program, you can do that using

```
System("open <pathToApp>");
```

Second part is to get notified of app's exit. Any of the IPC mechanisms will help you do this. [IPC Mechanism to communicate between C++ & Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592031/ipc-mechanism-to-communicate-between-c-objective-c) gives insight on a feasible option. In this case when the app is exiting, it can notify the C program.

This might not work if the app doesn't have a graceful exit. The case is when it crashes. Here the only way would be polling the pid. C program can get the pid of the launched app using ps command. Keep checking at an interval to see if the pid exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a C program, and want to execute another, separate application and wait till it finishes, the simplest option is to just use `system()` - see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html)

**Example:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...

system("myApp");
```