# How to implement MultiThread in Mac

Tags: multithreading

What's the equivalent of Window's CreateProcess() and WaitForSingleObject() in Mac OS X?
I want my C-Program to pause while my .app has finished running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fork() and exec() in OS X would be closest to CreateProcess() and for WaitForSingleObject(), you can use IPC mechanisms. [IPC Mechanism to communicate between C++ & Objective C gives insight on a feasible option.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592031/ipc-mechanism-to-communicate-between-c-objective-c) In this case when the app is exiting, it can notify the C program.